# Parse Cloud Code Error - 'Master Key is Required'?

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform, bitnami

Whenever I try to run this snippet of cloud code, I receive an error stating that:

Error generating response. ParseError {
code: 141, message: 'Push failed to send with error: master key is required'}

I've tried to follow some of the other solutions on the site such as using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` & `useMasterKey: true` but I haven't found success with any of these commands (possibly due to me using them incorrectly?).

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUser", function(request, response) {

    var senderUser = request.user;
    var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
    var message = request.params.message;

    var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
    recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
            where: pushQuery,
            data: {
                    alert: message
            }
    }).then(function() {
            response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
    }, function(error) {
            response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
    });
});
```

Swift function:

```
func testPush() {



    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "sendPushToUser", withParameters: ["recipientId": PFUser.current()?.objectId!, "message" : "Test notification"]) { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error occurred")
        }else {
            print("Sent successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where are you running it from? The error exists on the client side

Comment: I'm running it from my swift application. The error is present on the Parse dashboard logs and is returned as an error message when I try to activate it via my app.

Comment: Edited the original question just now. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's been awhile since using Parse, but I remember that Cloud code should allow you to to pushes no problem, and it seems your error is thinking you are trying to send a push from the swift code itself.

Comment: So rather than sending it through the swift code, I should send it from the actual server itself? Thought that the code was just making a request for the server to send the push?

Comment: Did you configure your masterKey in your index.js? `masterKey   : process.env.MASTER_KEY ||'your masterkey'`

Comment: Yep that was the issue. There was a single character that I had accidentally typed messing up the master key. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gellert Lee suggested

Did you configure your masterKey in your index.js? masterKey : process.env.MASTER_KEY ||'your masterkey'